# uwfmgr with excluded directory increases RAM usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-administration

While using the [Unified write filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwfmgrexe) on IoT Windows 10 the RAM usage is increasing.

On the drive `C:\ProgramData\VHD` is [execluded from filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwfexclusions).

```
uwfmgr.exe file add-exclusion "C:\ProgramData\VHD"
```

Current state of RAM usage on uwfmgr: `uwfmgr overlay Get-Consumption`: *20MB*

When now writing Data to `C:\ProgramData\VHD\Samples.vhd` the RAM usage is increasing to 2GB, then the system will break down.

Current state of RAM usage on uwfmgr: `uwfmgr overlay Get-Consumption`: *2048MB*

The question is not to incease the RAM limit. The question is how to avoid using *uwfmgr RAM* while writing on harddisk in excluded area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the filter functionality in Windows 7 to Windows 8, Microsoft changed the usage of the filter. All written data has no more passthrough, even if they are in excluded list.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwfoverlay

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/unified-write-filter

The change is not planned to revert back like on [Windows 7 EWF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27587)

There can be a workaround to use different harddisk, which is execluded automatically in Microsoft write filter.